# Async multiple download with retrofit get the data in response

Tags: android, async-await, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, deferred

Lets say that i have a model

```
data class PendingFile(segment: Int, fileHash: String, url: String)
```

So when i have a list with pendingFiles i want to download each file concurrently.

```
private suspend fun downloadLinks(pendingFiles: List<PendingFile>) {
        scope.launch {
            val deferredList = pendingFiles.map {
                async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    // runs in parallel in background thread
                    networkCallToGetData(it)
                }
            }

            // Waiting all requests are finished without blocking the current thread
            val listOfReturnData = deferredList.awaitAll()

            val (success, failed) = listOfReturnData.partition { 
                 // What should i put here??
            }

            if (failed.isNotEmpty()) {
                // Back off to the half size
                currentDownloadParts /= 2
            }

            if (success.isNotEmpty()) {
                // Continue double size
                currentDownloadParts *= 2
            }
        }
    }
```

I want my `success / failed` to be distinguished and i also want the lists to have the PendingFile models accordingly in order to know which one succeeded and which one failed. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can improve the concurrent code using `coroutineScope` see: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#structured-concurrency-with-async
2. Too see what failed and what worked you can use `null` as a fallback value in the list (or create a sealed class with Success/Failure values)

```
suspend fun downloadLinks(pendingFiles: List<PendingFile>) = coroutineScope {

    val deferredList = pendingFiles.map {
            async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                // runs in parallel in background thread
                try {
                   networkCallToGetData(it)
                } catch (e: Exception) { // might wanna adjust this depending on your use case
                   null // null here means failure, alternately you could use a sealed class with success and failure
                }
            }

           // Waiting all requests are finished without blocking the current thread
            val listOfReturnData = deferredList.awaitAll()

            val (success, failed) = listOfReturnData.partition { 
                 it != null
            }

           TODO() // rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem that the downloadLinks calls itself at the end??